# AJAX POST uploading files using javascript and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a simple file uploading service but I need a way to use AJAX to upload files using JavaScript, jQuery, PHP and AJAX (or just some of those languages). I have set up the home page and I want to make it so you can only upload a single file (not a folder) and it will create a random directory name of 6 random numbers and letters. It will upload that file to inside that directory it created. I don't know a single thing about AJAX and such as n00b. Please someone help me. Here's my files

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Anonymous File Uploading</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/custom.css">
        <script src="./js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    </head>
    <script>
        function upload() {
            if (document.getElementById("file-upload").value == "") {
                alert("Please upload a file first!");
            } else {
                if (!document.getElementById("terms").checked) {
                    alert("You must accept the terms and conditons before you can upload files.");
                } else {
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        beforeSend: function() {
                            status.empty();
                            var percentVal = '0%';
                            bar.width(percentVal)
                            percent.html(percentVal);
                        },
                        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
                            bar.width(percentVal)
                            percent.html(percentVal);
                        },
                        complete: function(xhr) {
                        bar.width("100%");
                        percent.html("100%");
                            status.html(xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
    <body>
        <div class="container top-padded">
            <div class="well">
                <h2 class="header">Anonymous File Uploading</h2>
                <input type="file" class="file-upload" id="file-upload"></input>
                <input type="checkbox"> I agree to the <a href="./terms.txt">terms and conditions</a> of using this site.</input><br>
                <div class="spacer"></div>
                <button class="btn btn-default center-block" onclick="upload();" id="terms">Upload</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</HTML>
```

POST.php:

```
file blank ( i dont know how to code ajax )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure AJAX can upload files, but you can do everything you're talking about with just PHP and HTML, but you'll need to spend some time learning PHP.  I would find one of the many online PHP tutorials to start.

As far as what you want to do, here is what you need to learn:

1. (HTML/PHP) How to upload a file
2. (PHP) How to create a directory

That's it, assuming you know enough HTML to create and use forms.